# HTACCESS RewriteRule changes URL OK but gives 404 page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla2.5

I'm building a new site using Joomla and I've selected 'Search Engine Friendly URLs' and 'Use URL rewriting' in the Global Configuration which gives good SEF URLs but not quite perfect!

If a link to a page doesn't have a menu item associated to it the URL would look like this:

> example.com/10-category/5-article

I want to remove the numbers and the hyphen using **htaccess** so it looks like:

example.com/category/article

I've made Rewrite Rule's in my htaccess file that looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-(.*)/([0-9]+)-(.*)$ /$1$2/$3$4 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(.*)/([0-9]+)(.*)$ /$2/$4 [R=301,L]
```

The browsers address bar now shows the URL I want, example.com/category/article but the page shows a 404 error!

Is it something to do with the Joomla SEF?

What am I doing wrong?

****Update****
The first RewriteRule which removes the hyphen only works OK by itself, I only receive the 404 error page when both RewriteRule's are active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a blind guess, Joomla probably needs those numbers to know which content to serve. It cannot just tell by the name of the category or article (in fact in most of these cases you can even leave it out), but it's the number that's important.

So when you're rewriting the URL without the numbers, you're requesting pages that Joomla has no idea how to handle, and it'll give you a 404. The only solution would be to write a plugin or something that maps the names of categories and articles to the corresponding IDs, but that's not going to be easy.

Concerning SEO, I don't think the number in the url is that much of a negative effect. If the rest of your website's SEO is good then this won't matter.

Comment: Hi Stephan, thank you so much for your very fast reply, impressive!!  This would tie up with my update above.  I've been using SH404SEF which worked and removed the numbers and hyphen but it's been giving me quite a few other problems hence leaving it alone and trying to sort things myself, but, it looks like I might have to consider going back to it to remove the numbers.  SEF is my main concern, but as you advised the numbers don't really matter too much but I would like good looking URLs too. Again, thank you so much for your reply, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: You're quite welcome. And yeah, I can imagine why you'd want prettier urls, I don't like this structure much either but sometimes it's the best you can do. Don't forget to accept the answer if no better solutions come up :).